# How can I find the API that a website uses?

Tags: javascript, python

I have a small personal project which consists of grouping several data from several websites in order to have them all in the same place.  Because of this, I use BeautifulSoup with Flask to be able to scrape the data.

However, I wish I could do the same for the following site: https://cartographie.ville.terrebonne.qc.ca/patin-exterieur/
but it's an interactive map and I can't take the information from each popup when clicking on a skate. After reading about it, I've come to the conclusion that the website in question must be using an API to display their data so I could be able to parse the datas, but navigating through Google chrome's developer mode I can't seem to find the correct api where all the data is stored. Does someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome DevTools "Fetch/XHR" tab, you can see new API requests as you move the map around.  Looks like the API response is `application/x-protobuf`, which is most likely a binary data response that you would need to parse.

[image]

Comment: That's protobuf. Google protocol buffers. Its just a component that the server is responding with to pass variables. Basically it's Googles JSON.

Answer (score 1):

They are using https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/maps-and-views/

Which is part of Esri. A big machine learning data science service.

You wont get far with this to be honest as you wont get any authorization.

Answer (score -1):

You can go through the website and press F12, then go to the **Network part** and **Headers** look for "Request Headers"
[image]